# Salesforce Screen flow search and display record information

Tags: salesforce, lookup, salesforce-flow

I'm working on a screen flow. The idea is to have a lookup component the user can search a contact. Then I would like to display the information from the Contact (Account Name, Contact Name, Number Email) and I would like to be able to have the user update that information if needed. I just stomped on how it can be done. I know it should be able to be pulled from the record ID in some type of way and maybe use an Assignment to display the information. Can someone guide me on a next step or if anyone has an instructional video would be helpful.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You wouldn't be able to display the looked up contact's fields on that screen as soon as you populate that field.  That would be something only possible in code (aura component or lwc).

What you can do, however is -

Get Record element after that screen element. (Get Contact, where Id = lookupcomponent.recordId)

Then EITHER:

- use the new Fields (BETA) option on another screen  [Fields (BETA)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJGbM.png)
  (this method is easier, doesn't have as much control and is limited on fields, depending on data type, you can use)
- add inputs one by one and set the default values [Add Fields One By One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XB1bs.png)
  (this method allows more control)

Then, you will need an update element.  If you used the Fields (BETA) you can just update the record variable.  If you did the inputs one by one, you will need to update the contact and set fields individually.

[Full Flow Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0RuJ.png)